# Is there a way to filter the messages of a conversation in Facebook Messenger by the "until" and "since" fields in Facebook GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was recently trying to fetch some messages from the GraphAPI node of "conversation".

Something like:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<conversation_id>/messages?fields=id,created_time,message,from,tags,to,attachments,sticker,shares&access_token=<access_token>&since=<some_unix_timestamp>"
```

This appears to just return ALL the messages in the conversation (of course in the usual cursor paginated manner of FB) without filtering the results by the "since" filter.
Same thing happens with the "until" one.

Now, I saw this bug report from 2017:
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/420363721670492/

It pretty much says that they decided not to support this functionality anymore.

This really does not make any sense to me!
Is there any way of fetching a specific batch of messages of a conversation without having to paginate through all of the history?

Has someone found a workaround or a better practice to fetch the messages without getting the rate-limiting raped?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

May the force be with you.

Shmax

Comment: _“This really does not make any sense to me!”_ - well, it doesn’t necessarily have to :-) The main purpose of this API endpoint surely is handling real-time messaging, and rather not to provide a full history that can be navigated through at will. So it _does_ make sense to remove this for performance reasons, if that helps them to better cater to the needs of the majority of users.

Comment: Well, I have to agree that I am probably not Facebook's top priority :)
"The main purpose of this API endpoint surely is handling real-time messaging" - are you saying this based on the documentation or is it just a logical deduction of the situation?

Comment: My own deduction. And previous discussions with FB engineers from a while ago, regarding other API endpoints and specific filtering options. It’s not limited to messaging, even stuff like just getting feed posts tends to get less reliable (posts missing, sometimes duplicated results on different paging sets), the further back one tries to go.